# Garbage collection in Flash Media Server

Tags: actionscript, memory-leaks, flash-media-server, reference-counting

I have memory leak in my project and I wonder how garbage collector working in Flash Media Server.

I have 2 questions:

1. Will FMS release objects from memory that have cycle references. For example when object A is has ref to Object B and vise versa.
2. Why FMS still consumes memory after application unloaded by idle timeout. For example there were no users connected then fms unloaded app after 20 minutes. Memory usage left at the same level (for a long period of time).

In general I miss some best practices of writing FMS code.
FMS 3.5.1 on WinXP